# iTunes Connect - entitlement error

Tags: ios

Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.homekit] must have a privacy policy URL for [English, Turkish]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary.

I didn't choose home kit entitlement in App ID. Where will I remove from this entitlement ?

Answer (score 2):

1. First check that HomeKit is off in your app's capabilities pane in Xcode:

[image: capabilities pane in Xcode]

2. Then remove HomeKit.framework from link step in the Build Phases pane:

[image: build phases pane in Xcode]

3. Then in the developer portal, in Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles, make sure HomeKit is disabled in your App's Identifier:

[image: app Identifier in developer portal]

4. Clean your project and remove derived data.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly have done all of this. But still it gives me same error. Im sure the app doesn't include anything about homekit. Maybe it can be different solution for this, can't be ?